# The fastest way to copy files from complex structure of directories

Tags: python, multithreading, directory, copy

I have a structure o directories: "Z:/{year}/{id}/{month}/{day}/{hash}/*.jpg"

In a python script, Which could be the fastest way to copy that structure to "C:/XD/{year}/{id}/{month}/{day}/{hashes}/*.jpg" ?:

Copying with:

```
for year in years:
  shutil.copytree(year, "C:/XD/{year}")
```

or using this way:

```
for year in years:
  # more fors
    for hash in hashes
      shutil.copytree(hash, "C:/XD/{year}/{id}/{month}/{day}/{hash}")
```

?

And how many threads I should use?

Comment: Why not time both approaches and choose the best?

Comment: Can't say which is faster without looking at the data you're trying to copy, why the emphasis on  multithreading ? shouldn't you first make it work in a single thread before thinking of multithreading ?

Comment: There are only images in the last node {hash}, Intermediate nodes don't save other kind of files.

Answer (score 0):

After measure time in 2 different process I found out the first way is the fastest, with only single for loop. And If I run that script in 4 parallel terminals is even more fast.

Comment: Please add what you have found in the question itself. It cannot be considered as a n answer to the question you posted